# SingleChildScrollView in GestureDetector does not work

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use ListView or other scrolling in GestureDetector, it does not work:

```
new GestureDetector(
      child: new Container(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        child: new Text("Short Content"),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red
        ),
      ),
      onVerticalDragStart: (DragStartDetails detail){
        print("onVerticalDragStart");
      },
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails detail){
        print("onVerticalDragUpdate");
      },
    )
```

above it work for drag detect but if i have other scroll in GestureDetector it will not work

```
new GestureDetector(
      child: new Container(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("Long content "),

          ],
        ),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red
        ),
      ),
      onVerticalDragStart: (DragStartDetails detail){
        print("onVerticalDragStart");
      },
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails detail){
        print("onVerticalDragUpdate");
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an `ScrollController` and assigned to the parent and the child widget. If the `SingleChildScrollView` has unbounded constraints in the `scrollDirection`, you have to add `shrinkWrap: true`.

**Example:**

Outside of the build method:

```
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
```

Inside of the build method, you can used it like this:

```
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    controller: scrollController,
    child: GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
        child: ListView(
          controller: scrollController,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Center(child: Text("Long content")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onVerticalDragStart: (DragStartDetails detail) {
        print("onVerticalDragStart");
      },
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails detail) {
        print("onVerticalDragUpdate");
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Images:**

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q2Ym.png)

[Debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIMMs.png)